# Usage of 'bovinely' when fastness or slowness are involved

Tags: phrases, adverbs, semantics, irony, animals

I know that in English 'I tried to go as slow as possible' and 'I tried to go as fast as possible' have a very different meaning, but I'm unsure how 'bovinely', before 'possible', change that difference.

> 1. 'I tried to go as slow as *bovinely* possible.'
> 2. 'I tried to go as fast as *bovinely* possible.'

Thus my question is: Can anyone explain what the semantic difference between (1) and (2) is?

In other terms, do you think that 'bovinely' nullify the difference between 'slow' and 'fast', so that one can indifferently use either?

Comment: It limits the range of fast and slow to the range that is possible for a cow.  Consider that *as fast as humanly possible* means as fast as it is possible for a human to go, which may not be as fast as a bovine (cows can out run humans)

Comment: DIfferent words mean different things. 'Fast as a cow' comes from the point of view of things much slower, 'slow as a cow' from things much faster.

Comment: *Unclear why you're closing*. Please clarify your specific problem or add a comment to explain exactly what you suppose to be unclear. As it's currently anonimously voted, it’s hard to tell exactly why you're closing.

Comment: As the title asks about the usage of *bovine* specifically, explain what really the sentences are supposed to mean, imply or emphasize. I can see a possible answer to your question based on my own understanding of it as it is, but would like you to first clarify.

Answer (score 1):

1. I tried to go as slowly as a cow could.
2. I tried to go as fast as a cow could.

Answer (score 1):

*Bovine* means, like a cow: having qualities (as placidity or dullness) characteristic of oxen or cows. *He stared at us with a stupid, bovine expression.* To use it for speed is, in my opinion, terrible, unless you are **possibly** referring to Imbabala, Bongos, or others which are in the FAMILY BOVIDAE: Subfamily:Bovinae: Tribe Strepsicerotini:
Genus [Tragelaphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragelaphus) (antelope-like): [bongo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongo_%28antelope%29), [imbabala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbabala)

These make sense for people:

> I tried to go as slow as humanly possible.
>   I tried to go as fast as humanly possible.

These make sense for oxen, cows, yaks, etc:

> It went as slow as bovinely possible.
>   It went as fast as bovinely possible.

Comment: Quite right. I suppose it's possible cows can metaphorically represent ***sluggishness*** in some other language. But not in English, where you ***move at a snail's pace*** when you're not making much headway. We do sometimes mention ***sloths*** though, so it's not all gastropods.